# My Philips TV turns on only after I plug it out many times. How can I fix it?

Tags: electrical, television

I have a 42PFL3507H/12 Philips TV which I bought in 2012. It hasn't been working fine for a couple of months now. It won't turn on normally when I press the power button either on the remote or on the screen. I have to plug it out of power and back in five to ten times before I can turn it on.

I have searched through the internet but none of the solutions worked. I have tried plugging it out of power and leaving like that for a while. I have updated the software to the latest version. I have even taken it to the certified Philips TV service, but the repairman said that it worked perfectly fine when he tried to turn it on, although he did not show me that it works fine so I'm a bit sceptical because it still doesn't work at home.

What else can I do?

Comment: Good question.   Welcome to H. I. S. E.!  To improve the question a little, it might be good to provide some identifying information like the model, year you bought it, etc.  Thanks for contributing!

Comment: sounds like a problem with the power supply, it's most likely on the way out. Maybe capacitors going bad? that would explain why the initial surge at power-on trigger the saftey shut down when the detected voltage levels are wacky. After a few aborts, there's enough residual charge to get them to perform enough in spec that it's not interrupted.  i would leave it on to avoid the problem, but be aware that it's a matter of time before it gets even worse.

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem with power because the red light that signals whether there is power is on.

Comment: Does it have an external power brick and low voltage input into the TV proper? Or is it mains power right into the TV?  Is it connectd via antenna or cable?  If you unplug the signal cables (cable TV, HDMI etc.) does it behave normally?

Comment: the red power LED could be naive, I doubt it's a comprehensive "everything's ok" indication, and even if it were, everything could be ok when the TV is off, but when asking the PSU for more power to turn the TV on, it's no longer ok...

Comment: @Harper Power goes right into the TV. It's connected via cable. I've tried plugging everything out and leaving only the cable for power connected, but it still didn't work.

Comment: @dandavis You are quite right, it was a bit too quick of a call that the power supply is OK just because the red light is on. I'm going to try to investigate the parts longneck suggested in his answer, including the power supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside an LCD TV, there are effectively just a few major components:

1. LCD matrix
2. Backlight
3. Power supply
4. Backlight driver (aka, high voltage power supply)
5. Main board
6. Video board
7. T-Con board
8. Speakers
9. Buttons
10. IR Receiver

Some of these items may be combined with others (control board and video board might be the same) or not used (backlight driver usually only needed for CCFL backlights).

Let's work through that list and assess the probability of each component causing the problem you have described.

- Your LCD matrix is probably fine. A failure here probably wouldn't stop the TV from otherwise powering on. A failed backlight probably wouldn't either.
- A bad power supply might work enough to turn on the red light you mentioned in a comment, but fail to respond to a power-on command. **A failed power supply is a likely candidate.**
- Your TV does not have a high voltage power supply.
- The main board is responsible for receiving your power-on command and controlling the power-on sequence. **A failed main board is also a likely candidate.**
- Your TV does not have a separate video board.
- A failed T-Con board is not likely to cause your problem. And I don't think your TV has one.
- There is a small chance that a shorted speaker is triggering a short-circuit protection mechanism, causing the TV to immediately power off. I would consider this unlikely.
- When the TV does work, you state you are able to turn it on using the on-board buttons and the remote, and when it doesn't work neither of them work. Therefore we can rule out the button board and the IR received.

There is a small chance that if you open up the TV and remove the power supply board, you might be able to identify a failed component and replace it. More likely you will have to replace the entire board.

Comment: It kind of sounds like a bad capacitor to me. When it is discharged by unplugging, it starts working again. This leads me to think the PSU or main board, like you said. If the OP can get a repair tech to spend some time diagnosing it, rather than plugging it it and "it works", it should be an easy and low cost fix. I've seen people replace capacitors in TVs fairly often.

Comment: to clarify one of your points: the TV is back-lit by LEDs, not CCFL.

Comment: When I turn the TV off, it always works immediately. Is that a sign that the control board is working fine?

Comment: I think it's equally as likely to be the power supply or the main board, but my gut is saying power supply.

Comment: @longneck A year later I still have the same issue. I never took the TV back to the repairman. I just left it on on for a year. That's why I haven't marked longneck's answer as correct. I have never really found out what was wrong with the TV. However, last week my dad turned it off by accident and now I can't even get that red power light to turn on even after plugging it in and out a million times (which worked a year ago). Supposing the problem is in bad capacitors or in a failed main board, is there a way to bypass the problem without changing the broken part?

Comment: @computercarguy Do you maybe know how to bypass the problem explained in my upper comment?

Comment: My advice still stands. There is a small chance that if you open up the TV and remove the power supply board, you might be able to identify a failed component and replace it. More likely you will have to replace the entire board.

Comment: @HinkoPihPih, yeah, what longneck said. There's no easy fix or workaround for this. You just have to get it actually fixed, or replace the TV.

Comment: @computercarguy Thank you! I have just one more question - how can I recognize the failed component on the power supply board?

Comment: It might be obvious: a cracked component that spewed black soot. Or it might not be. Step one is just to open it. If it's not obvious, take a (good) picture and post it here.

Comment: @HinkoPihPih, a capacitor may have failed with as little as a domed top. The cylindrical ones should have a flat top. Disk shaped ceramic caps crack open. And good luck finding it. There are dozens of large caps in a typical TV. And hundreds of tiny surface mount caps that don't look like a normal capacitor.

Comment: @computercarguy and longneck The problem was in the failed main board. I'm going to buy a new TV because it pays off more than buying a new main board for an 8-year old TV. Thank you both again for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like your outlet or receptacle is loose and needs replacing. If you have the plug in and twist to put some side pressure on the plug will it work? If so it’s time for a new outlet.

Comment: It doesn't work. I've tried plugging it in other outlets which I know are OK as well, and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem is failing capacitors. I have an old Panasonic 42PX60U with the same problem. If you remove the back cover and place a space heater directly in front of the power board, about 5 minutes of direct heat will have your TV starting like new. Test the capacitors, if you have the capability, and you will find several failing units. Replace them and you will be back in business.